# Gravity between Two Planets ... (I have the Solution but it doesn't make sense ... !)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, planets

So the Question is :

[image]

Two Planets that Have the masses of m1=M,m2=9M , Both of the planets have the radius of r the planets are Set to 16r away form each other ...

A. At what distance between the two planets will the total gravity force be equal to 0 ?

So the solution that I found is in the picture below :

[image]

But unfortunately I don't understand where did the 16R-x = 3x come from??! it is so confusing !

Comment: When you cancel like terms and cross-multiply, you get (16R - x)^2 = 9x^2.  Take the square root of both sides.

Comment: This is an algebra question, not a physics question. You may want to head over to the Mathematics stackexchange site. Vote to close.

Comment: @Pirx: In that sense, then just about *every* question on Physics.SE site should be asked over at Math.SE because it would involve math.

Comment: But, this is a question that involves *nothing but* (trivial) math.

Comment: it totally makes sense .... I'm sorry i didn't notice ...

Comment: @Pirx: again, most every question on this SE site could be construed as 'trivial maths' questions. The fact that there is a *physical basis* for the question means it is a *physics* question, not a mathematical one.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this then. In this case, there is absolutely *no physics* involved in the question *that is being asked*. Sure, the question does have a physical background, but from what the poster writes, it seems clear he has understood the physics of the problem. All s/he is asking is how to get from one algebraic expression to another one. No physics in there, at all.

Comment: I agree with @Pirx. The difficulty which the OP is having is with the algebra, not with the physical concepts. However, the OP probably does not appreciate this distinction, and the Math SE guys would probably see only the context and send the question right back here.

Answer (score 1):

Its just solving equation!
\begin{align}
GMm/x^2&=9GMm/(16R-x)^2
\\
1/x^2&=9/(16R-x)^2
\\
(16R-x)^2&=9x^2
\\
(16R-x)^2&=(3x)^2
\\
16R-x&=3x
\end{align}

Comment: Please see [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  help post to learn how to write your equations in a way nicer way i.e. in $\LaTeX$, in order to improve legibility. Thanks!

Comment: This might be better if you used there MathJax equation editor we have in the site and explained a little more.

Comment: @Pirx : Yes, I made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I will delete my comment.